# Modify ros2 code and build Autoware on that?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using Autoware.auto on Foxy. I want to modify the source code of ROS2 Foxy or Dashing(not contribution, just for own use) and build Autoware on my modified ROS2 version, is that possible?

As far as I know Autoware.auto is built on ROS image(ade) which cannot be modified, right? If yes, how could it done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366143/modify-ros2-code-and-build-autoware-on-that?/) by [runtao](https://answers.ros.org/users/60564/runtao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What does the ROS image mean, `ade`?

You can build Autoware.auto without using `ade` if you maintain the container image downloaded with `ade` by yourself.

If your Linux distribution is an apt-based system, such as Ubuntu, you can build Autoware.auto from https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/blob/master You might want to run the scripts in /.gitlab-ci.yml#L58 in order.

I apologize if I'm missing any, as I always use `ade`.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3